# how to make font size small in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

```
\begin{center}
\small
\setlength\extrarowheight{0.01pt}
\captionof{table}{Nomenclature}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\doublerulesep{.1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
 \hline
 \textbf{\small Symbol}    & \textbf{\small Description} \\
 \hline
 $E_{c , TL}$&  Total energy consumption in a day \\
 $R_{a}$ & ----------------\\
 $S_{a}$ & S--------------- \\
 $E_{a}$ & -----------\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

And I want to make the font size small whatever written in the table, however, I have used `\small` but it doesn't work in a tabular environment. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it does. The difference between `\small` and `\normalfont` is just not very large, so you maybe just didn't notice it.

There are in general two ways to go (and your example contains both):

- set a fontsize (`\small`, `\tiny`, etc.) before the `\begin{tabular}`, then all cells will have this fontsize
- use the fontsize only within a cell, then only this cell will have this fontsize

Note also: If you apply `\small` for the whole tabular, and you want a specific cell to be even smaller, then you need to use an even smaller fontsize in a specific cell (like `\footnotesize`).

See here an example of how the different fontsizes look like in a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\normalsize
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|}
 \hline
 \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} \\
 \hline
 $E_{c , TL}$&  Total energy consumption in a day \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|}
 \hline
 \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} \\
 \hline
 $E_{c , TL}$&  Total energy consumption in a day \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|}
 \hline
 \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} \\
 \hline
 $E_{c , TL}$&  Total energy consumption in a day \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|}
 \hline
 \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} \\
 \hline
 $E_{c , TL}$&  Total energy consumption in a day \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\tiny
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|}
 \hline
 \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} \\
 \hline
 $E_{c , TL}$&  Total energy consumption in a day \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `\small`  out of the `table` environment.

```
    \begin{document}

\small
       \begin{center}
        \setlength\extrarowheight{0.01pt}
        \captionof{table}{Nomenclature}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \setlength\doublerulesep{.1pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{5cm}|}
            \hline
            \hline
            \textbf{ Symbol}    & \textbf{ Description} \\
            \hline
            $E_{c , TL}$&  Total energy consumption in a day \\
            $R_{a}$ & ----------------\\
            $S_{a}$ & S--------------- \\
            $E_{a}$ & -----------\\
        \end{tabular}
       \end{center}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't change the output.

Comment: `\small` should be in `table` environment: `\begin{table}\small \begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\end{table}` or in your case `\begin{center}\small\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\end{center}` .... As you propose, all after `\small is in small fonts.